# Get log(n, 2) features after dummy encoding

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

During the dummy encoding (for example OneHotEncoder) we can drop first feature (with param: drop='first'). It helps when we have 3 features. It works because it's enough to have 2 cells to encoding 3 features like: (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0); also for 4 features: (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1). So I noticed that to encode n-categories it's enough to have math.ceil(log(n, 2)) features. But I can't find function (in sklearn/pandas) that allows to do this. I ask your help.

Comment: This is a computer science. we can encode 4 categorical attributes "A, B, C, D" one way (with OHE): {A: (1, 0, 0, 0), B: (0, 1, 0, 0), C: (0, 0, 1, 0), D: (0, 0, 0, 1)} or another: {A: (0, 0), B: (0, 1), C: (1, 0), D: (1, 1)}. And in both cases the features will remain independent. But the first approach gives 4 features while the second 2. So I want to have a minimum of total features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're searching for is `bin()` function which is a standard built-in in Python.

Suppose you happen to have a simple pandas `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":["a","b","c","x","a","c"]})
print(df)
   a
0  a
1  b
2  c
3  x
4  a
5  c
```

Then you may proceed as follows:

```
df["enc"] = df["a"].astype("category").cat.codes
max_enc_length = len(bin(df["enc"].max())[2:])
df["enc"]=df["enc"].apply(lambda x: bin(x)[2:].zfill(max_enc_length))
df = pd.concat([df["a"], df["enc"].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x)))], axis=1)
print(df)
   a  0  1
0  a  0  0
1  b  0  1
2  c  1  0
3  x  1  1
4  a  0  0
5  c  1  0
```

Note, linear models are out for such type of encoding.